# The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Tags: java

I'm having a problem when trying to run my program. What my program is supposed to do is to receive a number and compare it to an int. I understand that the program thinks that I'm trying to compare String with an int and not happy about it. What can I do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String age = input.nextLine();
        if (age < 50){
            System.out.println("You are young");
        }else{
            System.out.println("You are old");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare a `String` to an `int` using a numerical comparison-operator. [§15.20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) of the Java Language Specification describes exactly what you are seeing:

> The type of each of the operands of a numerical comparison operator **must be a type that is convertible ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs**.

Since `String` is not convertible to a primitive numeric-type, you cannot compare it against an integer. Therefore you have two options:

- You can convert the `String` into an `int` using `Integer#parseInt`:

  ```
  int age = Integer.parseInt(ageString);
  ```
- But in your case, since you are already reading in input, it would be better to bypass the whole `parseInt` bit and read in an `int` directly:

  ```
  int age = input.nextInt();
  ```

Keep in mind though that you still have to deal with the possibility of invalid input.

Answer (score 3):

You need `age` to be an integer in order to compare it to 50.

You have two options :

```
int age = input.nextInt();
```

or

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Note that both options would throw exceptions if the input you enter is not an integer.

Comment: This should definitely be the correct answer as `input.nextInt` is the way to go.

Comment: You can prevent exceptions from being thrown from the `Scanner` alternative by checking the input with [`hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) first.

Comment: `parseInt()` isn't better solution this problem, because method may throw `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 1):

Before comparing you need to convert it to integer using parseInt().

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the String as an Integer.

```
String age = input.nextLine();
if (Integer.parseInt(age) < 50) {
    System.out.println("You are young");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scanner class actually has an input method called nextInt() that you can use:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int age = input.nextInt();
// Comparisons
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare a String and a int values using "<",">","<=",">=" operators.  That is the problem with your code. to fix that you can either,
take input from the user as int by replacing the line 5 as `int age = input.nextInt();` 
or you can convert your age String to integer after taking inputs from the user using something like this `int intage=Integer.parseInt(age);`. Then you can replace your age variable with intage variable